# Android App crashing on some devices

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Android app, and I'm using an actual android device to execute the app, and it works just fine.
But when I try to send the APK file to another android device, so that I can execute it... The App doesn't even start on the other device. it crashes once launched.

- the device where it works fine uses the android version : 5.0.2
- the device where it's not working uses the android version: 4.4.2

Is there anyone who has an idea about this situation??? 
thanks

Comment: show stacktrace

Comment: Can you post the Stacktrace of the crash? And the code that it's crashing on?

Comment: Post the logs please

Comment: Actually I can't ... when I execute the app from android Studio using my usb cable.. it works fine. the app crashes only if I send the Apk file..

Comment: You must be sharing the installed APK, this happens when you do that with different versions of Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you are sharing a generated `debug APK`, and not simple an installed version of the application itself. To generate the debug-apk, click on `Build` > `Build APK`.

All built APKs are saved in project-name/module-name/build/outputs/apk/. You can also locate the generated APKs by clicking the link in the pop-up dialog that appears once the build is complete.